# Load page content and blog post index content (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I have a question about Wordpress' template structure and querying posts.

I have my templates setup where the (for example) archive-$posttype.php is built like:

```
get_header();

$args = 'page_id=18'; //Client Uses page
query_posts($args); the_post();

get_template_part( 'sub-header' ); 

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
<div class="content">
   <?php get_template_part( 'loop' ); ?>...
```

I do this to set my default $post variable for my sub-header.php file which prints out content from that page:

```
<div id="subheader">
   <h1><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'header_title', true)?></h1>
   <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'header_description', true)?>...
```

However, using this method on the home.php template, doesn't work:

```
get_header();

$temp_query = $wp_query;

$page_id = 119; //Client Uses page
#$post = get_page( $page_id );
$args = array('page_id' => $page_id);
$post = new WP_Query( $args ); the_post();

get_template_part( 'sub-header' ); 

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<div class="content">           
   <?php get_template_part( 'loop' ); ?>
   <?php get_sidebar( 'news' ); ?>
</div><!--.content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm curious why this works on one template and not on the home template. AND, am I going about this the wrong way? What's the correct way to have page content in the sub-header template that in most cases is ACTUALLY related to that current page the user is on.

Thanks!

Comment: I should clarify that my sub-header.php template, works fine without re-writing the WP_Query for all pages except a few customized situations like the custom post-type archive page, and the blog index page (which is not the homepage).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your problem exactly but if you are doing what I think, having a chunk of text from a specific page above another loop that pulls in posts of some sort or another I would use the template naming structure.

```
<?php /* Template Name: My Template */ ?>
```

This will allow you to use the standard loop to get content from whatever page the clients sets the template to (avoiding the static ids you are using).

Your home page bug could be due to it not being set as the posts page in the reading settings. As I understand it if a page is not set as the posts page it will act like a normal page unless you rewrite the query specifically.

Answer (score 0):

*"What's the correct way to have page content in the sub-header template that in most cases is ACTUALLY related to that current page the user is on."*

Rather than trying to tie together two unrelated pages/posts, it might be easier to use a custom field tool. My current favorite is [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

With ACF, you can add supplemental fields (image, wysiwyg, file upload, 14 total field types) to your posts and pages, then easily pull the custom data into your template. It's very well documented and extremely easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

So, I changed the way my sub-header.php template works. Basically some basic checking on what type of page/post was being set/called then dynamically pulled the relevant page info.

```
<?php 
if (is_page()) : 
    $header_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'header_title', true);
    $video_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'youtube_video_id', true);
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-thumbnail', array('class'=>'visual-element'));
    $description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'header_description', true);
elseif (is_home()) :
    $page_id = 119; // News page
    $page = get_page( $page_id );

    $header_title = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'header_title', true);
    $video_id = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'youtube_video_id', true);
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'post-thumbnail', array('class'=>'visual-element'));
    $description = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'header_description', true);
elseif (is_archive()) :
    $page_id = 18; // Client Uses page
    $page = get_page( $page_id );

    $header_title = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'header_title', true);
    $video_id = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'youtube_video_id', true);
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'post-thumbnail', array('class'=>'visual-element'));
    $description = get_post_meta($page->ID, 'header_description', true);
endif;
?>
<div id="subheader">    
    <h1><?php echo $header_title; ?></h1>
    <?php if ( $video_id ) : ?>
    <iframe class="visual-element" width="300" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video_id;?>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <?php elseif ($thumbnail) : ?>
    <?php echo $thumbnail; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $description; ?>
</div><!-- #subheader -->
```